# Windows .url links that point to same address when copied over or deleted

Tags: url, installation, hyperlink, software-distribution

This is really annoying, we've switched our client downloads page to a different site and want to send a link out with our installer. When the link is created and overwrites the existing file, the metadata in windows XP still points to the same place even though the contents of the .url shows the correct address.  I can change that URL property to google.com and it points to the same place when I copy over the file.

```
[InternetShortcut]
URL=https://www.xxxx.com/?goto=clientlogon.php  
IDList=
HotKey=0
```

It works if we rename our link .url file. But we expect that the directory will be reused and that would result in one bad link and one good link which is more confusing than it is cool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at here: http://www.cyanwerks.com/file-format-url.html

It explains there's a Modified field you can add to the .url file. It also explains how to interpret it.

Answer (score 1):

.URL files are wierd (are they documented anywhere?)

Mine look like this and I don't seem to have that problem (maybe because of the Modified entry?)

```
[DEFAULT]
BASEURL=http://www.xxxx.com/Help
[InternetShortcut]
URL=http://www.xxxx.com/Help
Modified=60D0EDADF1CAC5014B
```