# How do you package clickable url's with your application?

Tags: deployment, cross-platform, cross-browser

I asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141251/windows-url-links-that-point-to-same-address-when-copied-over-or-deleted) a while ago but didn't get a satisfactory answer, so I was wondering if there was a different approach a guy could take.

What is the format for making a web link that you can deploy with your application? One that might show up in the start menu as a link to said app vendor's website.

It should work in any modern OS and with any reasonably modern browser (i.e. >= IE6, although I'm not sure that's a relevant issue)

Comment: Please elaborate. It's not clear what you're asking. What's a "weblink"?

Comment: Just something in the start menu that launches a browser, not too dang complex, but more obnoxious than you may think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no cross-platform way to do this.

- Freedesktop-compliant systems can use xdg-open
- Mac users can use open
- Debian derivatives can use sensible-browser (or install xdg-open, usually)
- Windows users can use *.url files
- Or, of course, you could implement xdg-open and package it with your app on systems that don't have it
- Or implement your own util that's completely different and associate it with the right files

Answer (score 0):

The format is different on different platforms.

On Windows, you can use a `.url` file. [Here's](http://www.cyanwerks.com/file-format-url.html) a description of the format. You can also create one by just dragging a URL onto the desktop or into a folder. A simple example:

```
[InternetShortcut]
URL=http://stackoverflow.com/
```

On the Mac, you can also create a URL file by dragging a URL to the desktop. The format appears to be a file with a `.webloc` extension, containing a [plist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Property_list) containing a `dict`, mapping the key `URL` to the URL in question:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" 
    "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>URL</key>
    <string>http://stackoverflow.com/</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```